# Invalid table name when calling mysql procedure

Tags: mysql

Here's my procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `couponExpires`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `couponExpires`(IN couponID BIGINT, OUT 
expirationDate TIMESTAMP)
BEGIN
SELECT purchaseTimestamp
INTO expirationDate
FROM CouponUnique
WHERE couponUniqueID=couponID;
END$$
```

Here's my call:

```
CALL couponExpires(1, @expirationDate);
SELECT @expirationDate;
```

This gives me a blob. The blob 19B, which when I click on it, it gives me the error "Invalid table name."

And, yes, the table exists:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CouponUnique` (
`couponUniqueID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`couponPackageID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`userID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`purchaseTimestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`useTimestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 07:00:01';
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a *function*, not a *procedure*:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS couponExpires$$
CREATE FUNCTION couponExpires(IN couponID BIGINT)
RETURNS DATETIME
BEGIN
    RETURN (
        SELECT purchaseTimestamp
        FROM CouponUnique
        WHERE couponUniqueID=couponID);
END$$
```

Then

```
SELECT couponExpires(1);
```

Another problem you're going to have is you are using the wrong datatype. You should use DATETIME, not TIMESTAMP. TIMESTAMP automatically updates with the current time whenever you update/insert a row, and you CAN NOT provide a value for it - even null.